# Solution to an ODE depending on arbitrary exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider a function $h(x, t) = \exp(t\cdot f(x) + g(x))$ given, and $\alpha(x, t)$ unknown. Can we say anything about the following non-homogenous ODE:

$\partial_t h = -h \cdot \partial_x \alpha - \alpha \cdot \partial_x h$,

with $\alpha: \mathbb{R} \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (the time requirement can be relaxed.)

Comment: It would be more clear if we write $h(x,t)=\exp (t f(x)+g(x))$

Comment: So $\alpha=\alpha(x)$? It doesn't depend on $t$?

Comment: $\alpha$ does depend on $t$, but we don't have the time derivative in the ODE.

Comment: Then I guess $t$ is irrelevant here. We have $h_t(x,t)=f(x) h(x,t)$, so we obtain an ordinary differential equation

Comment: It already is, no? We are interested in derivatives with respect to $x$. I am interested in understanding how the particular functional form of $h$ determines the form of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's forget about $t$ as a variable, and simply rewrite the equation as:

$$(\alpha(x) h(x))'+\alpha(x) h(x)'+f(x) h(x)=0$$

Expanding, we have:

$$h \alpha'+2h' \alpha+fh=0$$

We will also rename the function (again, treating $t$ as a constant parameter):

$$s(x)=t f(x)+g(x) \\ h=e^s \\ h'=s' h$$

We now have:

$$\alpha'+2s' \alpha+f=0$$

This is a simple 1st order linear ODE, which can be solved by usual methods.

Then we remember that:

$$s'=t f'+g'$$

So we also have $\alpha$ depend on $t$.

Comment: Thank you Yuriy, but you've misinterpreted the formula - I've rewritten it in the question. There is no derivative with respect to the product.

Comment: You should have been more clear. Derivative to the left of the product always means differentiation of the whole product

Comment: Agreed, I should. Sorry.

Comment: @Forgottenscience, you can still do the exact same thing I did to get an ODE for your function